# What is the value of the infinite sum of $1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1.3}{3.6}+\frac{1.3.5}{3.6.9}+\frac{1.3.5.7}{3.6.9.12}....$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My attempt:

$1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1.3}{3.6}+\frac{1.3.5}{3.6.9}+\frac{1.3.5.7}{3.6.9.12}....$

=$1+\frac{1}{6}$.$2\choose 1$+$\frac{1}{6^2}$.$4\choose 2$+$\frac{1}{6^3}$.$8\choose 4$+.......+$\frac{1}{6^{n-1}}$.$2n-2\choose n-1$+...........

But I am perplexed as to what should be my next step?

Options:

(A)$\sqrt{2}$

(B)$\sqrt{3}$

(C)$\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}$

(D)$\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}}$

One edit $t_n=\dfrac{1.3.5.7.....(2n-3)}{3^{n-1}(1.2.3....(n-1))}$

$=\dfrac{(2n-2)!}{(6^{n-1}(n-1)!(n-1)!)}$

$=\dfrac{1}{6^{n-1}}$.$2n-2\choose n-1$

Is this going to help me?

Comment: Adding the first three terms lets you exclude all options but one... That's not satisfying in any way, but if they are stupid enough to give you those options, I guess that's on them.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Oh gee thanks a lot..

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee How did you know this stuff on the first place? I mean I want to see the flow of your thought process.The process is really splendid.

Comment: @Saradamani, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2345390/proof-of-logarithmic-series  OR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function and   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series